# "Could not save. Disk full" error message from KTimeTracker

Tags: kubuntu

I keep getting the error message mentioned in my post from KTime Tracker.  I don't know what made it start... but it keeps popping up every few minutes, even if the app is not running.  I found this link:

http://userbase.kde.org/KTimeTracker/Developing#How_to_reproduce_a_stale_lock

But I don't think I quite understand how I can use this information to resolve my problem.  Sorry.  I'm just new to linux.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So is your disk really full?

Comment: If you're not sure how to check, try running `df` in the terminal, and pasting the output in your question.

Comment: May often be a simtom of a stale lock: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181301

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my misbehaviour.

Digging some further into this issue, I think I have at least the solution for **my** instance of the problem: for reasons best known to themselves, there were **two** instances of ktimetracker running ("ps aux | fgrep ktime" showed this)! Both try to save the state and, occasionally, they are so in sync that both try to save at the same time and one of them loses because the lock file for the saving process already exists!
I killed the second instance and now it's quiet.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please note that the box you typed this in was called "Your Answer", meaning it is reserved for answering the question, not adding any 'me too' (as they are refered to) comments!.

Comment: @JosefMöllers You may want to [post a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), if you think your problem may differ from the situation here in any way. Also, it's been several months since this question had any activity...so you might want to post your own question anyway.